# Vote counts don't update on posts when votes are invalidated

Tags: bug, voting, caching, score

When votes are invalidated on posts, either due to voter deletion or invalidation by CM's, the votes on the posts are not updated until someone clicks to "View the upvote and downvote totals", or actually votes on the post. This affects the total score display both on the user's profile and on the post itself.

Here are screenies:

First, the question list of a user with invalidated votes:

> [image: question list of a user with invalidated votes]

Next, the view of the question itself, prior to expanding votes:

> [image: the view of the question itself, prior to expanding votes]

Finally, the expanded view, which now shows the correct counts:

> [image: the expanded view, which now shows the correct counts]

Once the count has been updated via expanding or voting, page refreshes or new views now also immediately show the correct information.

It doesn't seem to be a *time-based* caching issue, as I've let some of these go three days to see if they were automatically updated, but they are not. Hard refreshes, viewing while logged in or off, and different browsers make no difference, either.

The main issue here is that this can leave a very wrong signal as to the usefulness of some posts; that signal having been meant to be killed by the invalidation. But these posts (answers, in particular) will remain displayed at their 'fraudulent' vote score, rather than their real ones.

I propose, then, that vote counts be updated on posts when a user's votes are invalidated. Either way, the update should happen at some point, and I think there's a little bit of an integrity issue as far as the voting system goes to update it automatically. There was one 'ring' today which was giving individual posts in the ring 7 or more fraudulent votes, for instance. Bad!

Please fixie?

<sub>(Tagged 'Bug' and not feature request as I believe this behavior is not intended.)</sub>

Comment: I always thought this was due to caching. I swear I've seen it automatically update after a certain duration, without manually displaying vote details.

Comment: @BradLarson Perhaps someone else has caused an update in the meantime? I've actually gone through users that *other mods* have handled and done this. In fact, the example above is from such a thing.

Comment: This was on all questions by a particular user, so that seemed unlikely.

Comment: True, for normal users, but I'm not normal. ;) When I do it, I do it on all their posts. But that doesn't mean that's actually the explanation. Perhaps there's some other trigger.

Comment: I've just come across the behaviour too (on [mathematics.se]). I've triggered the update on three affected posts by viewing the vote score, will see if other posts of that user get updated automatically. But, I sure would like to have the user removal take effect immediately. Doesn't matter when one ordinary user was removed, but if somebody has seven sockpuppets removed at once, it makes a big difference.

Comment: Seems the scores were updated yesterday evening. So it is just done late.

Comment: @DanielFischer ahhh, good to know; I worried that this would not be easy to see on Stack Overflow just because of volume of visits. Knowing that they do eventually update on other sites makes me feel better about it.